# Cannot load anything on Tomcat 7 : configuration issue

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, configuration

I'm currently developing a web project running on Tomcat 7 and I cannot see anything who's suppose to be on Tomcat (blank page when I do a HTTP request in my browser).

#### My Modus Operandi:

- I launch a new instance of server in locahost (apache-tomcat-7.0.34) within Eclipse (I work with Indigo and tried with Juno as well)
- Tomcat's ROOT folder has been pasted in the 'wtpwebapps' folder of all my servers in my Workspace
- I add a simple web project on this server instance and try to access it from a HTTP request and I get a blank page. If I try to run a .html file of this web project on this server, I get a 'HTTP 404 Not Found' Error.

#### What I tried:

I tried to build the whole configuration from scratch (new Eclipse, new Apache-Tomcat) and I still get the same result. But when I do that from my personal computer at home, everything's working fine!!

I tried to put an old version of my code or a tutorial project, but nothing can be launched (therefore, it must be a configuration issue).

I checked the server.xml and web.xml files and nothing looks suspicious (I can paste them if you want but those are the same than those who worked at home)

The only thing I can think of is that I changed the internet connection (and the IP address) of the computer I'm working on, but I don't think it could make any difference when trying to reach localhost, right?

When I follow the steps of the [very good tutorial](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html), I do get a blank page on the 'Run Tomcat' topic, but I don't get the Tomcat welcome page once I copied the ROOT folder into "wtpwebapps".

Does someone have any idea where it could come from?

Comment: Try right clicking on the project, configure, convert to faceted form. Then make sure you have Dynamic Web Project selected.

Comment: Hi Adashr, thanks for your reply.
I don't have this option. The 2 only option in the Configure menu are :   
 - Convert to Plug-in Projects  
 - Convert to Maven Projects  
But even without any projects, I should see the welcome page of Tomcat, right? So I don't think it's about the configuration of the project itself but more about the configuration of eclipse or tomcat or my machine or whatever else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, finally got the solution.
I was about to format my computer when i realize that the port 8009 was actually used by another process.
I thought that's the kind of things who are checked when you launch a Tomcat server within Eclipse but it didn't show any error.
The HTTP request went through the port 80, but as the default AJP port is already in use, Apache could not forward this request to Tomcat, therefore a blank page was returned.

At least that's my understanding of this situation...

Hopefully this may help someone who'd run into a similar situation.

Thanks for your help.